# node.js socket io https

Tags: node.js, https, socket.io

I'm trying to establish a WebSocket (with node.js/socket.io) on an
HTTPS protocol. But the client still keeps on polling and could not find the server although the server seems fine and listens.

This is what I have done so far. Could you see anything wrong with it?

My assumption is there is something not right with the certificates which I am using. I encrypted the server with plesk "lets encrypt" and took the certificates from this procedure is that right?

---- server side ----

```
var fs      = require('fs');
var express = require('/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/node_modules/express');
var https   = require('https');
var app     = express();

var server  = https.createServer({
    key:  fs.readFileSync('file.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('file.crt')
},app);

var io = require('/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/node_modules/socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);
```

---- client side -----

```
var socket = io('/', {rejectUnauthorized: false, secure:true});
```

---

This is what the client gives me continuously:
https://foo.de:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MF9zjE6

Comment: Please copy the error message into the question instead of a link to a broken service.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't tell what error message you get it's a little hard to identify your problem. Perhaps you should try getting your socket to work and then afterwards try to implement https.

Maybe you should try and simplify it a bit like this.

Server:

```
var express         = require('express')
var app             = express()
var server          = require('http').Server(app)
var io              = require('socket.io')(server)

server.listen(8080);
```

Client:

```
var socket = io();
```

This piece of code should create your socket and your express app. Then you could try and change http to https and it should work aswell.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the answer. It turned out to be a little topsy turvy. Now it works exactly the way i wrote like in my question but i changed on one hand the client call with var socket = io('https://localhost', {rejectUnauthorized: false, secure:true}); and tried another certificate. After all i put it in the right order and suddenly it worked ! PS : there was no error at all which i could have posted.